# How to write data at particular cell in excel/csv file in jmeter using beanshell?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I am trying to write the data in excel or CSV file using beanshell. But i am able to write the data in excel sheet but unable to write the data at particular cell in CSV file.

Below is the code.

```
var response = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); 
f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/adityak/Desktop/K/app.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print(response);
f.close();
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Why are you "not able to write the data". Can you write in it at all? Please explain the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. CSV file doesn't have "cells", it is plain text file with delimiters, mostly commas as CSV stands for [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)
2. Since [JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
3. Assuming all above:

   - Switch to [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language
   - use [File.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines()) function to read the existing file
   - split it using delimiter via [String.split()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#split()) function
   - replace value which is there with the new one.

For example if you have file like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

and want to replace `5` with `hello` the relevant Groovy code would be something like:

```
def csvFile = new File('/home/dtikhanski/Desktop/test.csv')
def lines = csvFile.readLines()


def secondLine = lines.get(1)
def entries = secondLine.split(",")
entries[1] = 'hello'
secondLine = entries.join(',')
lines.set(1, secondLine)

csvFile.withWriter{ out ->
    lines.each {out.println it}
}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Replace CSV]